# Javascript function call with )(

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

In JavaScript I have a function, for example:

```
function foo() {}
```

I can call it like this:

```
foo()
```

Or like this:

```
foo)(
```

Why does thesecond approach work? I don't get any errors. Is this a node.js bug? I tested on ubuntu terminal - node v0.10.37. In Chrome console second approach doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work. It's a syntax error. (Node 0.10.35 anyway, and surely in any other non-broken JavaScript environment.)

Comment: It shouldn't work, and if it does, there must be something else at play.  The spec doesn't allow that kind of thing nor does any language I know.

Comment: There's image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yKFQG.png

Comment: It's because when Node evaluates the console input, it wraps it inside `()` so it becomes `(foo)()`. There's a duplicate question but it's rather hard to search for.

Comment: @Juhana `function foo() {console.log(123)} var f = "foo)("; Function("(" + f + ")")()`

Comment: Try it in a normal script (not on the console).  It will be an error there.

Comment: I get the same output as your screenshot in Node 0.10.37. In Node 4.1.0 I get '...' which is Node expecting more code entry. The console in Chrome throws an error as expected.